# Cache not enabling

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, full-page-cache

I'm trying to enable the cache in magento that stopped overnight. When I turn shows success message but not active. 
[image]

I tried to activate programmatically and with mysql but without success.

I also tried to disable and then enable.

Comment: What have you tried? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: try flush cache storage, or take any 3rd party caching mechanisms out of the mix via `local.xml` (if any defined). You can also quickly disable the local codepool. Also a server stack details and cache tags in local.xml. Turning on developer mode in `index.php` as well as `error_reporting` may shed some light as well.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error today.

I cleared cache, checked log files, made sure I'm using the right database and all.

After  searching for an hour I got the issue. There was another xml file named "local1.xml" lying in app/etc folder. I deleted it, and everything came back to normal.

Hope this helps someone, someday.

Comment: I had the same problem . it is very strange but deleting extra local.xml files in my app/etc folder made it fix. i was stuck in it from last hour and you saved me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

thats a caching issue...

try to clear all your caches after enabling them.

If this does not work, try to clear your cache provider (filesystem, memcache, whatever you use)

Comment: I tried to do this ... I deleted the folder var/cache too... And this isn't permission error because the files and folders are being recreated.

Answer (score 4):

- (re)check your file/folder permissions on the server
- Try to reboot server or just httpd and mysql services
- Look into table "core_cache_option" and verify if the values are all "on" (value = 1)
- Look into your server logs if you can find an error, there might be an issue which needs to be solved

Good luck